# java.util.InputMismatchException и как с ним бороться

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток. Решаю задачу, нужно ввести с клавиатуры 2 числа, одно типа `int`, второе с плавающей точкой, т.е. `double` или `float`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
       int  a = scanner.nextInt();
       double b = scanner.nextDouble();
```

Привел кусок кода который соответственно проблемный, исключение выдает прямо на строке где вводится `double`. Я знаю, что это исключение лезет когда несоответствие типов, но у меня все соответствует! Пример исходных данных:

```
50 1.88   
14 1.42    
55 2.81
```

Comment: а какое из чисел в исходных данных соответствует переменной `d` (`int d = scanner.nextInt();`)?

Comment: не не , это я ввожу отдельно , количество значений у меня для решения задачи. Сейчас уберу чтоб не вводило в заблуждение.

Comment: А цикл там точно нужен?

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = 0;
double d = 0;

while (true) {
    try {
        i = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine().trim());
        d = Double.valueOf(scanner.nextLine().trim().replace(",", "."));
        break;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка ввода");
    }
}
System.out.println(i + " * " + d);
```

Сделайте так. Это пользовательский ввод, посему прилететь может что угодно, в т.ч. совсем не цифры. Поэтому берите строку, обрезайте пробелы, меняйте запятую на точку в случае с даблом и пытайтесь ее затолкать в инт или дабл. Этот код не упадет, а цикл в совокупность с блоком, перехватывающим исключения, заставит пользователя вводить значения до тех пор, пока не будут введены именно числа.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/i052cn. то ли я что не так делаю, то ли что. Этот код постоянно выводит ошибка ввода.

Comment: Самое интересное то, что даже когда я просто пытаюсь ввести `double`, он выдает это исключение. Что то тут не так , я ведь уже работал с дробными числами, scaner их легко читает, вроде..

Comment: с моим вариантом тоже падает? с тем же исключением?

Comment: с вашим вариантом выводит ошибка ввода для каждого числа. Решил проблему тем что сначала исходные данные вставил в текстовик , там заменил все точки в дробных числах на запятые, и приняло без исключений)

Comment: в моем варианте сканер читает построчно. т.е. вы вводите число и нажимаете enter, первым идет тип int, аналогично с double. для текстового файла в аргументах сканера передается файл. и насколько я понимаю double использует точку, а не запятую...

Comment: В общем, факт остается фактом, с запятой приняло, с точкой нет. И я ввожу все числа разом, не построчно.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что лучше делать как-то так

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
     int a = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
     double b = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
}
```